# Is it possible to implement microservices with oData.net

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, odata, microservices

I've been reading about the [Microservice Architecure](http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) and with the limited valuable information available on internet, I believe, I have a fair understanding of it from the theory point of view. I understand that on a high level this architecture suggests to move away from [monoliths](http://microservices.io/patterns/monolithic.html) and have small, independent services. However, all the examples that I see on the internet are suggesting to write loosely coupled windows services (daemons in case of non MS implementations) connected to an [ESB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus). I understand that writing small, loosely coupled web services that adhere to [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) also fits the bill of micro services.

That said, oData.Net services, where all oData controllers (micro services?) are deployed as a monolith, is a clear violation of the Microservices Architecure pattern. Is it a correct statement to make that oData.net is not designed to work as micro services? If your answer is no then please explain with help of a an example. Also, help me understand, how to have the API gateway pattern in the mix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ODATA do fit micro services. However, micro services are not a good fit for odata. What I mean is that there is really nothing that stops you from exposing OData in a micro service.

However, by doing so you typically expose a large set of the inner data structure in the micro service. That would in turn increase the coupling between different services. By doing so, you make it harder to change a service due to dependencies.

My own personal rule of thumb is to expose as small API as possible from each service. And the data structures that I expose are not the same as the internal ones. They might be flattened or a union between data in different internal entities.

My reasoning is: If you are going to create separate services, try to separate them as much as possible. Else you are just building a monolith that happens to run in a couple of different windows services.

Comment: yes, you should be providing "view models" via the API and never the actual domain objects from the database.

Comment: I do not agree with @jgauffin, Odata is just a query language for http it has nothing to do with the project's database structure. It provides a standard way of querying the data and can take advantage of all the oData tooling like Auto-generation of client etc.  One can write Pact test for microservices to make sure any change in one microservice does not break anything in the consumer microservice.

Answer (score 1):

oData is entirely valid as a method for exposing a microservice; exposing a explicit table however isn't microservices. So I don't agree completely with jgauffin. There is no reason why an API cannot be made available using oData. Where I do agree with JGauffin is that an API should have a small, and planar footprint that is decoupled from the detailed data structures of the source or destination. Therefore it is up to the service calling it to transform the API, but means that the generic format of the API can be reused as long as the business need is there, and technical platforms switched as required.